# How to pass different options to cppwinrt.exe

Tags: c++-winrt

I have a cppwinrt project created from the visual studio template and I would like to pass different options to cppwinrt.exe to test out what's available in the compiler. Is there a menu in visual studio where I can provide command line arguments, similar to how you can provide arguments to the MSVC compiler from the Configurations Properties in VS2017?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no property page available in Visual Studio for configuring cppwinrt.exe command line options.  If you're curious, you can simply run cppwinrt.exe from a developer command line prompt (assuming you have a recent Windows SDK installed) and it will provide documentation for the command line options.  You can then use these in a custom build rule if you need complete control of the options.

**Update:**

[C++/WinRT NuGet Version 2.0.190605.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/2.0.190605.7) now provides a property page to modify C++/WinRT project properties, including an "Additional Parameters" field for command-line options:

[image]

Comment: Is this still accurate? It seems that Visual Studio projects generated by the more recent wizard implementations do provide a *C++/WinRT* property sheet in the *Common Properties*, that allow at least some control.